# PHP on IIS has no data at $_POST

Tags: php, wordpress, post, iis

trying to run wordpress blog as part of ASP.NET app on Windows and IIS server and faced with a problem when server can't get POST parameters from submitted form.
Basically, i went thru all steps of numeric manuals across the web and ended with PHP that looks like working, but $_POST array is empty on every form submit. $_GET array has values when passing them thru query.

Short installation summary:

- PHP downloaded and unpacked (tried v7, v8 thread safe and unsafe)
- php.ini added and configured (key values in table below)
- IIS configured with handler mapping (*.php, FastCGI, php-cgi.exe, folder or file, script policy)
- FastCGI settings added with vars **PHPRC**=#path-to-php.ini# and **PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS**=1000

I can confirm that **there are no redirect** happens so, params can't be lost during it as page and resources serves with 200 code. Post requests also has payloads.
Settings stats as per phpinfo:

- **enable_post_data_reading** = On
- **post_max_size** = 128M
- cgi.check_shebang_line = On
- cgi.discard_path = Off
- cgi.fix_pathinfo = On
- **cgi.force_redirect** = Off
- cgi.nph = Off
- cgi.redirect_status_env = no value
- cgi.rfc2616_headers = Off
- **fastcgi.impersonate** = On
- fastcgi.logging = Off

Also, here is some values during form POST-ing:

- **$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']** = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- **$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']** = 120 (changes based on typed values of course, but not null or zero)
- **$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']** = POST

Not sure what may be wrong and why $_POST is empty every time.
Please give any suggestions.
Thanks

**Additional info:**

- echo file_get_contents("php://input") = empty string

Comment: Enable IIS Request Tracing, reproduce the issue, then share one of the `fr000000.xml` XML files.

Comment: Perhaps examining the contents of `php://input` might help diagnose the issue?

Comment: @RobEyre,  echo file_get_contents("php://input") shows as empty string

Comment: The trace shows that a bunch of unnecessary Managed modules are running for your request - try setting `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">` and using `<clear />` inside `<modules>` (in `<system.webServer>`).

Comment: @Dai, thanks for suggestion. I'm trying to run php in a subfolder /blog while in root it's ASP.net app running that requires modules. Nevertheless, for test purposes i and clear and false to attribute - no effect. Actually, clearing modules triggered error in configuration

Comment: @Dai, I set up additional site in IIS, just empty folder with same content, and tested it with very simple .php file with POST form and echo of $_POST, and it works! So, it looks like your assumption is close to the true - something in root app breaks php request. Assuming, I should figure out just how to split apps in IIS to forward all /blog/* requests to php app

Comment: Are you using a separate **application scope** (not just a _virtual directory_) for the `/blog` subdirectory?

Comment: @Dai, I started with converting /blog directory to application under the site in IIS and assigned it's own app_pool to it, but it seems like web.config from root site inherited, so, trying to access .php triggers error about missing .net dlls

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @Dai's suggestion in comments it turned out that root app's config affected on php app in subfolder in a wrong way.

Issue was not reproduced on clear IIS website, so, in this case it was needed to clean request pipeline with config cleanup. It looks like it's possible to solve this with reverse proxy setup, but I decided to go with following way by just "cleaning" subfolder's config:

- I converted folder with PHP code to an application (right click in iis >> Convert to Application)
- Assigned newly created APP POOL to it (just for sure)
- Additionally, to prevent config inheritance (as there was an error about missing dlls), i wrapped **< system.web>** and **< system.webserver>** nodes in root web.config with **< location path="" inheritInChildApplications="false">**

Comment: Oh, in a simpler way, you ended up with PHP and ASP.NET Core handlers to compete with each other, because if you follow all basic documentation, the settings are mapping them both to all incoming requests. So, the changes you proposed in this answer are specific to your own case. By distributing requests to PHP/ASP.NET Core handlers based on the URL (root app under a site, or another app under a site), this approach works.